# Why does calling my CABasicAnimation not work in viewDidAppear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

In `viewDidAppear` I call the following code:

```
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[self.view addSubview:myView];

[myView setProgress:0.3 animated:YES];
```

That last line calls this method:

```
- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress animated:(BOOL)animated {
    self.innerPie.hidden = NO;

    self.innerPie.strokeEnd = progress;

    CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    pathAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    pathAnimation.duration = 3.0;
    pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.progress];
    pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress];
    [self.innerPie addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEndAnimation"];

    self.progress = progress;
}
```

Yet the animation *never* starts when I load the simulator. Why? Has the view not already appeared, as indicated?

Oddly enough, if I use `dispatch_after` with a 0 second delay (instant) it *will* show.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [myView setProgress:0.8 animated:YES];
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution (delayed performance) is excellent, so there's really no problem. The only question is why your code doesn't work without the delayed performance. I suspect it has to do with these lines:

```
[self.view addSubview:myView];
[myView setProgress:0.3 animated:YES];
```

You have ordered the MyView to be added to the interface, but apparently it hasn't *really* been added yet, at least not in such a way that the interface has settled down and we are ready to add an animation to the layer render tree. Your delayed performance accomplishes exactly what's needed: we wait one cycle of the run loop, and now the interface (including the added MyView) is ready to rock and roll.

Comment: So would it be safe to call this more or less a bug on Apple's side, that my `dispatch_after` remedies?

Comment: No, I wouldn't call it a bug at all. The fact that certain important stuff happens only after all of your code has completely finished running, at the end of the runloop / transaction, including layout, drawing, and animation, is an important fact about how iOS works; it is part of its efficiency and ingenuity, and something all iOS programmers need to understand. And for that very reason, delayed performance to let the runloop cycle once is a valuable programmer's toolbox technique.

Comment: By using that technique, you are simply taking things in order, saying to the runtime: (1) add my subview; (2) call me back when you've done all the housekeeping associated with step 1; (3) ah, thanks for the callback, now add this animation to the render tree.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you.