# UIBarButtonItem doesn't update title until after function returns

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uibarbuttonitem

I'm creating an app that loads an sniffing-based database from one site, and all of this is done by "onlineSetup" method.

Since this method could be stuck for a while, I would like to set a statusText as "Connecting" so the user knows he has to wait. The problem is: the 'setTitle' is ignored until the method onlineSetup returns, even if the onlineSetup method is called after.

```
- (void)modeSwitchChanged:(id)sender
{
if (self.modeSwitch.isOn)
{
    [self setStatusText:@"Buscando dados: YokaiAnimes" withColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    if ([self.db onlineSetup]) [self setStatusText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Animes encontrados: %d",self.db.animes.count] withColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    else
    {
        [self.db offlineSetup];
        [self setStatusText:@"Falha: internte desconectada." withColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [self.modeSwitch setOn:false animated:true];
    }
}
else
{
    [self.mainTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self setStatusText:@"Buscando dados: Memória Interna" withColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.db offlineSetup];
    [self setStatusText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Animes encontrados: %d",self.db.animes.count] withColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
[self.mainTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)setStatusText:(NSString*)t withColor:(UIColor*)c
{
[self.statusLabel setTitle:t];
[self.statusLabel setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:c,NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens in the interface until after all your code finishes running. That's how iOS works. Thus if you want your change in the interface to happen now, you need to get off the main thread for a moment to let the runloop finish cycling before you proceed.

```
- (void)modeSwitchChanged:(id)sender {
    if (self.modeSwitch.isOn) {
        [self setStatusText:@"Buscando dados: YokaiAnimes" withColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             // call onlineSetup here
        });
     // ...
```

Indeed, if `onlineSetup` is truly time-consuming, you should to it on a background thread (not `dispatch_get_main_queue()`), because if you hog the main thread for too long, you will be punished with instant death (well, your app will, anyway). But then of course ultimately you must get back on the main thread to make any further changes to the interface. This is why GCD is so great; it makes this kind of thread-switching easy and safe.

In fact, if you are doing networking, you should definitely be using asynchronous networking. The ability to do this is built right into iOS; if you are deliberately doing synchronous networking, stop right now and fix that. You get a callback at the end and you can get back on the main thread at that point.

Comment: For further details and examples of how to get off the main thread and back on with GCD, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch38.html#_grand_central_dispatch

Comment: And see my discussion here (in the answer and comments) on getting off the main thread to let the interface update before proceeding: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22446912/341994

Comment: hey man, thanks for the fast response :) First of all, I have no experience with GCD, so I'm having a hard time to get what this 'dispatch' commands actually do. Should I include the whole if-else statement in the dispatch or just the onlineSetup call?

Comment: I tried calling onlineSetup from the dispatch_async but I get nothing. The label isn't being set, and the code performs as normally. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Hey @LucasSunsi, ok, instead of `dispatch_async` let's try it using `dispatch_after` with a zero-length delay as in the code at the bottom of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22446722/341994

Comment: Okay, now it kinda works, but I decided to study more on this subject and not just copy random code until my task is done. :) Thanks for the awesome help!

Comment: @LucasSunsi Excellent idea. You should probably be concentrating on the networking part - if you were doing that synchronously, do it asynchronously instead and the whole problem will be solved plus you'll be doing it properly.